# How to Insert Content in tinymce Editor without triggering focus on editor?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

How can i insertContent in the tinymce active editor without triggering the focus on editor ?

**UseCase :**
When i execute insertContent on editor and the editor is outside of the view port
It inserts the content and scrolls the editor into view -  But i don't want the editor to be focused or scroll into view.

As per the docs, you can actually pass additional arguments to insertContent command setting skip_focus to true...but it doesn't seems to be working...

```
activeEditor?.insertContent(htmlContent as string, {skip_focus: true});
```

I have tried execCommand to insert content passing skip_focus to true as well...this time it didn't insert the content...

```
activeEditor.editorCommands.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, htmlContent, {skip_focus: true});
```

**Tinymce version :**
"tinymce": "^5.5.1",
"@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.7.0"

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this

```
activeEditor?.setContent(activeEditor.getContent() + htmlContent);
```

but looking for a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
editor.hide();
editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, text);
editor.show();
```